# Why can't I enable SSH on several ports?

Tags: ssh, sshd

In order to train my networking skills, I am trying to get a Raspberry Pi to listen for ssh connections on both ports `22` and `2222`. My endgoal is then to practice using `ufw` in order to allow connections on port `22` from my WAN and on port `2222` from an ethernet connection only.
For now, `ufw` is disabled and I am just trying to set `sshd` to listen on the two aforementioned ports. Here are the only uncommented lines from my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
Host *
    Port 22
    Port 2222
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

However, I get a `Connection refused` error when trying to ssh on port `2222`, regardless of the originating machine. For some reasons I cannot explain, ssh does not seem to be listening on port `22`:

```
paupaulaz@pi2:~ $ ss -tlnp | grep 22
LISTEN    0         128                0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN    0         128                   [::]:22                  [::]:*
```

I of course tried both restarting sshd and rebooting the Raspberry Pi, and I have no user specific ssh config file.

Thanks a lot for any help !

Comment: You should modify the /etc/ssh**d**_config, not the /etc/ssh_config file.

Comment: Also, the `Host` directive is not supported in sshd_config; and the `Port` directive cannot be used in a conditional block like `Match host` -- the server cannot listen only for some hosts on some ports ;-)

Comment: Of course, that makes a lot of sense.. Thank you so much ! For the sake of completeness, I think you forgot the `ssh` directory in the path (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), or at least this is what it looks like in my Raspbian distro. Cheers and thanks again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh_config` is the configuration file for the SSH *client*. There, the `Port` option tells it which port to connect to. That could be different for different servers, so you might want to have one port specified in one `Host` block, and another in another block. But you can only form a connection to just one port at a time, so I suppose the latter directive takes effect. (Don't remember for sure, though.)

If you want to make the *server* listen on a particular port or multiple ports, you need to put the `Port` directives in `sshd_config` (d for daemon). I don't think there's a `Host` directive for `sshd_config`, but there's `Match Host`.

(But if you want to accept connections from certain source hosts on one port, and connections from other hosts on another port, you may need to use a firewall / packet filter for that.)